# Making objects run at the same time

Tags: java

I have 5 Bus objects and 15 bus stop objects. The program is supposed to run such that all the 5 bus objects run at the same time between bus stops.

[image]

in the output, the first bus object runs for the expected time and stops before the second bus runs and that continues till the 5 bus. 
  However, I need all the buses to run simultaneously between bus stops and stop at the same time.

Bus Class

```
public class Bus {
int capacity;
int bus_id=0; 
busStop position;
double time=10.0;



public Bus(){
  this.capacity=50;    
  this.bus_id=bus_id;
} 


public void spawn_bus(int bus_total,int position){
    for(int i=1; i<=bus_total; i++){
        bus_id=i;
        System.out.println("Bus with ID:"+i+" created");
       // setBusPosition(i,Bus_simulation.getPoissonRandom(position));
        busMovement(i,Bus_simulation.getPoissonRandom(position));
    }
 }
public void setBusPosition(int bus_id, int stop_id){
    System.out.println("Bus : "+bus_id+ " at Stop :"+stop_id);
}        
public void busMovement(int bus_id, int stop_id){
    double t=0.0;
   while(bus_id>0 && t<=time){
        t++;
       stop_id ++;
       if(stop_id>15){
           int stop_id_m= (stop_id % 15);
       System.out.println("Bus :" +bus_id + " now at "+stop_id_m +" at Time "+ t);
       }else{
       System.out.println("Bus :" +bus_id + " now at "+stop_id +" at Time "+ t);   
       }
     }
   } 
  }
```

Main Class

```
public class Bus_simulation {


public static void main(String[] args) {
  int bus_number=5;  
  int total_bus_stops=15; 
  // bus obects
  Bus bus = new Bus();
 // bus stop onnjects
 busStop stops = new busStop();
 getPoissonRandom(5);
 stops.create_busStop(total_bus_stops);
 bus.spawn_bus(bus_number,5);


}

public static int getPoissonRandom(double mean){
Random r = new Random();
double L = Math.exp(-mean);
int k = 0;
double p = 1.0;
do {
    p = p * r.nextDouble();
    k++;
} while (p > L);
return k - 1;
}

  // Generate Bus }
```

Comment: What instructions did you get from the professor or TA? Are you supposed to use threads, or are you supposed to run all busses in steps in the same thread?

Comment: threads isnt a requirement

Comment: the goal is to test waiting time as buses pick up passengers @ Erwin Bolwidt

Comment: Objects are data and don't "run". *Threads* of execution are what run, executing instructions in sequence. If you want concurrent execution, you need either to create multiple threads yourself or to use a library (such as `Executor`) that does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than write the whole program I would like to point out what might be the biggest issue related to your question.

You are really only creating a single Bus

```
Bus bus = new Bus();
```

And then you are simply changing the bus number and then moving it around again.  You might want to create a

```
List<Bus> buses = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead.  And then put 5 buses in the list and interact with them in a loop.

```
buses.add(new Bus());
buses.add(new Bus());
...
buses.forEach(bus -> ...)  // this is for Java8+
```

spawn_bus method is not doing what the method name implies.

Old-school java might be...

```
for (Bus bus : buses) {
    ...
}
```

And if you wanted to interact with them in parallel (threads), taking advantage of Java streams...

```
buses.parallelStream().forEach(bus -> ...)
```